# Do I need to add a lock on a function that returns a copy of a container?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
class Manager {
public:

    list<Employee> getEmployees() {
        // Do I need to lock here?
        return emps_;
    }
    void addEmp(Employee emp); //Here I have lock
private:
    list<Employee> emps_;
};
```

Instance `Manager` is shared between multiple threads.
Do I need to add lock to the `getEmployees` member function?

I am pretty sure that i need a lock since the complete list is copied , so any modification that will be done in the meantime (until copy will finished )  can break the copy operation.

I am just asking this because i got few opinion that there is no need to lock.

**Edit**:

Since its clear now that need to lock , my question is how to do this with minimum overhead. 
By doing below solution you copy the list twice.:

```
list<Employee> getEmployees() {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
    list<Emp> tmp  = emps_; //Copy 1 
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    return tmp;//Copy 2
}
```

Comment: You need to read about multithreading and think about this. Why would you want a lock there? How would a it help? Could you redesign the API to actually solve your problem? The question in multithreading is rarely as simple as "Should I have a lock here? Yes/No". Voting to close as "overly broad". Sorry!

Comment: @MagnusHoff - as i add to the question i am pretty sure that lock needed , but i have an argue on it, and you can see that even professional peoples , like oachim Pileborg from answer below think that this is not required lock, so this question need to be asked.

Comment: Well, the answer to the question "Is the copy constructor of std::list thread safe?" is clear: No, it's not thread safe.

Comment: @WhozCraig i am running on Ubuntu . can you give me any reference that WORM lock can be more expensive from read-write lock?

Comment: Lets get you up and running with your write-mutex first. You can integrate a worm off-line. i'll update the answer.

Comment: @user1495181: read about RVO (return value optimization), your compiler is likely to not do a redundant copy of the container.

Comment: @Mat tnx . I believe you ment to  the tmp container and not the original one.

Comment: The redundant copy would be tmp container to "returned" container yes.

Comment: Since you are using C++, consider the scoped [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The whole list is copied, but the source of the copy may be under modification. stdlib containers support fully-concurrent unlocked read access. Writes on the other hand...

if you're going to be writing to this list when the copy is potentially being made, you need to lock it down. a SWMR (Single Writer Multi Reader) lock is ideal for this, btw, especially if you have a dozens or even hundreds of threads that need to be making copies, with only the occasional write needed. Even then, starvation of the writer-request is a real-concern to be addressed by the implementation of the locking class, but not for the scope of your question here (no pun intended).

Regarding your update, I'm a massive fan of scope-released locks when they are appropriate, and they are so in your case. I.e. a scope-object wrapper around your mutex that latches it on entry, and unlatches it on scope-exit.

I'm quite sure the boost:: guys have such a thing easily accessible, and for that matter C++11 may too (I've not taken that plunge yet due to work schedules; no downtime ugh). But you want something like this:

```
list<Employee> getEmployees() 
{
    scope_lock latch(&mtx);
    return emps_;
}
```

The `scope_lock` above is just a simple class that latches the mutex on construction, and unlatches it on destruction. This protects against the very-real possibility that an exception thrown in your copy-construction will not perma-hang your mutex. Think of it as an exploitation of automatic destruction to unlock a mutex. [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for the win.

I hope that makes sense. For small get'ers like that such things are ideal. Again, many toolkits including boost will likely have such things built in, and if any boost guys read this please cowboy-up and lend a pointer. The example above is about as trivial a scope lock ideal as you can get.

Finally, for a SWMR, the logic is exactly the same. the only difference is the lock will take an additional argument of whether you're requesting read-or-write access.

Comment: One last - i am using in this -  lock_guard<mutex> guard(mtx_);  is this ok? is this will unlocked only after the return value was copied?

Comment: template-based lock-wrapper with auto-unlock on destruction? *perfect*. I've not used it but so long as *it* throws an exception on failure to lock the mutex, it will be a nice fit for your usage. As I said, just make sure the *same* mutex is latched under writes as well.

Comment: With regards to a scoped lock: it's almost necessary, since copying a `list` can throw.

Comment: @user1495181 Destructors of local variables are called _after_ any return value has been copied out.

Answer (score -3):

In your case I would say that a lock is not needed, at least not with the code you show us. The reason is that the whole list is *copied*, so each thread that call the function will get its own private copy of the list.

Comment: But it is quite conceivable that the lock should be held while copying, is it not?

Comment: @MagnusHoff: Depends on how you define thread safety and use case. Always-Lock-On-Every-Read can be a total performance killer, but sometimes it might be needed.

Comment: @phresnel: Exactly. And we don't have that information, which is why I voted to close. :)

Comment: @phresnel His "read" does a deep copy of a `list`.  The hit for taking a lock in this case will be marginal.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I would still argue that it depends, especially on the size of the list. And double especially if the function gets inlined and merged with calling code, then optimized.

Comment: @phresnel Regardless of inlining, copying a list will involve some dynamic allocation.  Which is relatively expensive (and probably involves locks internally as well).  And what are the alternatives?  If he's modifying the list in another thread, then some sort of synchronization is required.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True that for the current revision of the question. In the first revisions of the question there was no information about whether the other threads mutate the list, though. Personally, I would neither advice to always lock inside a copy-operation, neither would I advice to never lock then; even if the overhead is small, it is still overhead, and it is also source-code-overhead.

Comment: @phresnel I wouldn't advice to always lock inside a copy-operation either.  But for a more fundamental reason: the granularity is often (usually?) to fine.  And if you need a lock at a higher level anyway, then the lower level lock becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I have somewhere a piece of code that lets you manipulate image buffers. The image buffer itself has no "set_pixel" (or however you'd like its name). The "set_pixel" method can only be reached by using a "locked_surface" RAII object. Not sure if there's a name for such pattern, where the object has no manipulation methods at all, but makes available a second, (almost) save interface. However, that was a rather big lock, in relation to what happened during locks.

Comment: I have to concur with James on this. Having *any* object that is even remotely potentially volatile via multiple threads of execution *must* be latched in some fashion. likelihood of volatility is not a computational factor; it is a bit as far as i'm concerned. If it can be, then it is. Unless the author of the objet proclaims it thread-safe (and STL has proclaimed the exact opposite for write-access) *you* are not only responsible, but are outright foolish NOT to protect it. Statements like "it depends, especially on the size of the list" are a recipe for disaster imho.